# Fuseki service capabilities - programmatically

Tags: jena

I am starting a fuseki server with the provided configuration file (see below).  What I would like to do is to retrieve the capabilities of the service once it is created.  The reason being, there could be multiple such SPARQL services (available over the net but capabilities are not know to me) and I want to select some based on their capabilities (e.g., services with update capabilities).  Is there anyway to find that (i.e., service capabilities) out programmatically?  Any advice regarding this would be much appreciated.

### Configuration file

```
@prefix :        <#> .
@prefix fuseki:  <http://jena.apache.org/fuseki#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:   <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix tdb:     <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#> .
@prefix ja:      <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .

[] rdf:type fuseki:Server ;
   fuseki:services (
     <#animal_service_pellet>
   ) .

# TDB
[] ja:loadClass "com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDB" .
tdb:DatasetTDB  rdfs:subClassOf  ja:RDFDataset .
tdb:GraphTDB    rdfs:subClassOf  ja:Model .

<#animal_service_pellet> rdf:type fuseki:Service ;
    rdfs:label                          "TDB Service (RW)" ;
    fuseki:name                         "animals/pellet" ;
    fuseki:serviceQuery                 "query" ;
    fuseki:serviceQuery                 "sparql" ;
    fuseki:serviceUpdate                "update" ;
    fuseki:serviceUpload                "upload" ;
    fuseki:serviceReadWriteGraphStore   "data" ;
    fuseki:serviceReadGraphStore        "get" ;
    fuseki:dataset                      <#inferred_pellet> ;
    .

<#inferred_pellet>
  a ja:RDFDataset;
    ja:defaultGraph [
                      a ja:InfModel;
                      ja:reasoner [
                                    ja:reasonerClass "org.mindswap.pellet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory";
                                  ];
                      ja:baseModel <#data_and_ontology_graph>
                    ];
  .


<#data_and_ontology_graph>
  a tdb:GraphTDB ;
  tdb:location "TDB_LOC" ;
  .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same question has been asked on the Jena users mailing list.

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-users/201206.mbox/%3C4FC884AE.5020409%40apache.org%3E

Try the DatasetRegistry - there is one global one, accessed via it's get() static.

org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.DatasetRegistry

The other way is to read the configuration file as RDF and look in that.

The configuration parser is in FusekiConfig

In the future, there will be support for SPARQL service descriptions [1].  Contributions welcome.

[1] http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-service-description/

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for the tips.  Yes, I did mail the jena user list as well; I was trying to reach the wider community by posting here too.  I have thought about using DatasetRegistry before posting the question, but my issue is that, I need to access to remote SPARQL services.  The second option wouldn't work for me either, due to the same reason.  I am excited by the reference you have passed me - that could be the solution I am after and yes I would like to contribute to that effort.

Comment: Btw, how could I use the "get" static method of "org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.DatasetRegistry", if I am running a fuseki service locally?  Should I just use 

Fuseki.init();
DatasetRegistry dsr = DatasetRegistry.get();

I seem to be getting 0 datasets references though I have 2 services deployed.